# executing win32ole script on remote windows machine through telnet

Tags: perl, telnet, win32ole

I am trying to create a word document on a remote windows machine. What I am trying is to telnet to the remote windows machine and run a perl script that creates word document through Win32::OLE. But it doesn't seem to work. Is this possible? Because my script has {visible} set to 1 but will that telnet session have access to instances of word application? Atleast I tried it didn't work.

Comment: Please let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: OLE exception from "Microsoft Word": Command failed Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x800a1066 in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "SaveAs" C:\Users\Administrator>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telnet may not be the best tool to accomplish this, I'm not sure what kind of permissions it has. I recommend using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), which allows remote command execution on windows servers. If it works locally, it will work using PsExec.

For example:

```
PsExec.exe \\remotecomputer -u userName -p Password Perl C:\path\to\file\file.pl
```

You can use the -s flag to run as system account, and the -i flag to run it interactively on the desktop. Without the -i flag, it will run in the console session.